# reduce by one for a content in my db on rails with only a button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want my code do that, when someone press the booking button, the guest-capacity associated with the event will be reduced by one.
Below is my code:

```rb
# show.html.erb
<%= link_to "Booking", event_path(@event), method: :booking, :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
<hr>
```

```rb
# events_controller.rb
def booking
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event.update_column( :guest_capacity, @event.guest_capacity-1)
  redirect_to @event
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`.update_column` is pretty dangerous to use since it skips all validations: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns.

What you can do is:

```rb
def booking
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event.decrement(:guest_capacity)
  @event.save
  redirect_to @event
end
```

or

```rb
def booking
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event.guest_capacity -= 1
  @event.save
  redirect_to @event
end
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm getting 'Couldn't find Event without an ID' now. And I change the line in show.html.erb to <%= link_to "Booking", event_booking_path(@event),:class => 'btn btn-danger' %>. My route is 'resources :events do
    resources :comments
    get 'booking'
  end'. Could you help me with this?

Comment: @yy01699 Two things: you want `get 'booking'` to be a `patch` request, since you're updating an attribute. Second, you need to define the `id` in the route as well, since you are trying to send that as well. Something like: `patch 'booking', on: :member`. This way the event id is available in `params[:event_id]`

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes